# R portable not starting from an UNC folder

Tags: r, unc, rscript

I downloaded a portable version of R (3.4.3) for Windows (7) and put it in an UNC folder.

I would like to start R from this UNC folder but I get the following error when launching R.exe or RScript.exe :
"CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory. UNC paths are not supported. Defaulting to Window directory". Then the console crashes.

Does anyone have an idea to solve this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: Map a network drive? Otherwise ask the R developers why they have this restriction.

Comment: Thanks. Mapping the network drive resolves the issue.
More precisely, I mapped the network drive with a VBS script, then changed the directory to be within the mapped network drive and finally launch R successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Mapping the network drive resolves the issue.

More precisely, I mapped the network drive with a VBS script, then changed the directory to be within the mapped network drive and finally launch R successfully